# What are the defenses of a Shaman's spirit companion?

Tags: dnd-4e, shaman

The Shaman's *Call Spirit Companion* feature in Player's Handbook 2 (page 120) says the following about the Shaman's spirit companion:

> The spirit can be targeted by a melee or ranged attacks, although it lacks hit points. If a single melee or ranged attack deals damage to the spirit equal to 10 + one-half your level or higher, the spirit disappears, and you take damage equal to 5 + one-half your level. Otherwise, the spirit is unaffected by the attack.

This makes it clear that the spirit companion can be attacked, but what are its defenses?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *Call Spirit Companion* feature has the Conjuration keyword. In the Player's Handbook 2 appendix, page 220, the following is said:

> Normally, a conjuration cannot be attacked or physically affected. If a conjuration can be attacked or physically affected, it uses your defenses.

Neither the original text nor errata changes to Spirit Companion include any exception to this general rule, so the Spirit Companions indeed use their caller's AC, Reflex, Fortitude and Will.